# FANN Error 11: Unable to allocate memory

Tags: python, neural-network, fann

In the Python implementation of FANN, I got this error from

```
from pyfann import libfann
ann = libfann.neural_net()
ann.create_standard(4, 2, 8, 9, 1)
#FANN Error 11: Unable to allocate memory.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug in create_standard and the other simple creates. The workaround is

```
ann.create_standard_array([2,8,9,1])
```

same for `create_sparse` and `create_shortcut`.

Comment: This is not specific to Python. This happens in the core C library, and is fixed by this answer.